# keyup and keypress do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with comments system when the user click the button write a comment i append a textarea to the document so he write his comment and save it .
I want to add a charachters counter to this textarea but when add the jQuery code nothing happened it gives me no response to any keyup or keypress .
My code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        var limitnum = 120; // set your int limit for max number of characters
    $('.comment_area').keyup(function(){alert('test');
      limits($(this), limitnum);
    });
});
```

the appended textarea code:

```
$("#section_bar").after('<p id="counter"><span>0</span> characters</p><textarea rows="4" cols="50"  id="" class="comment_area" name="reply_area" ></textarea><a class="comment button small black" href="#!" id="reply_'+match_id+'"><span>save comment</span></a>');
```

I want to know why the keyup or keypress oes not work is it related to the fact that i do not have the textarea when the DOM created and loaded(cuz i append it after that) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation, as you cannot attach event handlers in this way to elements that are not present when the DOM is initially rendered.

You can do this, like so:

```
$('#section_bar').on('keyup','.comment_area',function() {
  // Code here
});
```

This should help: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because your `textarea` has been added dynamically to the DOM so all the events for this `.comment_area` textarea will not be available.In this case, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach `keyup` event to this newly added `textarea`:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#section_bar').on('keyup','.comment_area',function() {
    alert('test');
    limits($(this), limitnum);
});
```

Comment: Yep only if keyup event bubbles up the DOM `:/`

Comment: Yes, it is. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/): Because of event bubbling, all key presses will make their way up the DOM to the document object unless explicitly stopped.

Comment: Fine `:)` I know there are some form field specific events that do not bubble up ... was just wondering if keyup was part of this "collection"

Answer (score 0):

If the element doesn't exist yet you can always register the event to a parent element and use the selector in on():

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.comment_area', function () {
// ...
});
```

Now the event is caught at the body element, but your function is only called if the event target matches the given selector.